Is $\sqrt z$ continuous and differentiable at $z=0$?
In other words, does the complex limit:
$$\lim_{z\to0}\sqrt z$$
Exist and equal $0$? ($\sqrt\cdot$ denotes the complex square root function).
If so, how would you evaluate it using the epsilon-delta definition?
I think the limit exists, although I'm not sure about the derivative, since intuitively the limit would diverge.

First of all, what is $\sqrt{z}$ in this case? With real numbers it is clear: for $x\geq 0$ we define $\sqrt{x}$ to be the unique non negative square root. But in the complex case, what is $\sqrt{z}$? Which of the two square roots do you choose for each $z$? This is a problematic function which usually requires choosing a branch.

Square root is more tricky with the complex numbers.  As for the positive real numbers, a non-zero complex number has two square roots.  However, there is not such a neat way to pick one as the principal value.  You will need to read up on branch vuts.

Note that $|\sqrt{z}|=\sqrt{|z|}$

Assuming we have selected a branch of $\sqrt{z}$, we have $$(\sqrt{z})^2=z\implies |\sqrt{z}|^2=|z|\implies |\sqrt{z}|=\sqrt{|z|}$$
Therefore, $$\lim_{z\to 0} \left|\sqrt{z}\right|=\lim_{z\to 0} \sqrt{|z|}=0$$ as $|z|\to 0$ and the real square root is continuous at $0$. This means $\sqrt{z}$ is continuous at $z=0$.
As for differentiability, notice that $$\left|\frac{\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{0}}{z-0}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right|=\frac{1}{|\sqrt{z}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}\to +\infty$$
when $z\to 0$, so the limit of $\frac{\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{0}}{z-0}$ cannot be finite and thus $\sqrt{z}$ is not differentiable at $z=0$.

It is not continuous on any neighbourhood of $0$, it is continuous at $0$.

Why are you evaluating the limit of $|\sqrt z|$ instead of $\sqrt z$?

@Elvis $\sqrt{z}\to 0\iff|\sqrt{z}|\to 0$, by definition.

Definition of what? I'm missing a lot about complex analysis, I'm studying it for the first time right now.
Also, how can a function not be continuous on any neighborhood of $0$, but be continuous at $0$?

A function $f$ has limit $c$ at a point $z_0$ if $|f(z)-c|\to 0$ when $z\to z_0$. Simply take $f(z)=\sqrt{z}, c=0,z_0=0$. About the second question, continuity is a local property, so what happens at a point does not affect other points: this also happens in $\mathbb{R}$.

No singularity at all, the square root is continuous at $0$ as proved above.

@NtLake That depends on the branch selected for the logarithm, suppose that we choose $[-\pi,\pi)$. Then take any point $c$ on the negative part of the real axis. Any sequence approaching $c$ from above will have an argument that tends to $\pi$, while any sequence coming from below will have an argument that tends to $-\pi$. This results in the square root of those sequences converging to, respectively, $\sqrt{-c}i$ and $-\sqrt{-c}i$. A similar argument works for any other branch

May I have a reference about the definition of limit for complex functions? Like a Wikipedia page or something.

It is exactly the same as for $\mathbb{R^2}$. See, for example, this

Yes the limit exists and it is 0, we can even set aside the branch cut ambiguity since this one doesn’t depend on that.  If you write $z = re^{i\theta}$ and we say $f(z)$ is some branch cut of $\sqrt{z}$, then we have that $f(z) = |\sqrt{r}|f(e^{i\theta})$. Notice that we are now taking the limit as $r \to 0^+$. Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ and $r < \epsilon^2$, then $|f(z)| = \sqrt{r}|f(e^{i\theta})| = \sqrt{r} < \epsilon.$
